# 301 redirect wildcard not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have this 301 redirect in my `/var/www/html/.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com [R=301,L]
```

It redirects `olddomain.com` to `newdomain.com` but the address at address bar remain `olddomain.com`

The second issue is if I do:

`olddomain.com/hello` or `olddomain.com/page/2/comment`, it doesn't redirect to `www.newdomain.com`

What should I do to able make it redirect all links to `www.newdomain.com`?

**Thanks for helping!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your olddomain.com and newdomain.com are hosted on same server, then seems like your current Rewrite would create loop. This may be why you never see hostname change in browser. I would add RewriteCond to avoid possible loop.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```